# Searching through a list recursively in Coq

Tags: list, coq, theorem-proving

Im trying to search for an object in a list, and then perhaps return true if it is found; false otherwise.

However, what I have tried to come up with is incorrect. I would really appreciate some guidance. I need the function to search through the list of elements by comparing the head of the list with the element concerned, if not a match, then recursively put the rest of the list through the function and repeat, by matching the head of the list.

```
Fixpoint find (li:list Interface){struct li}: list Interface :=
match li with
| nil => nil
| y::rest => find rest 
end.
```

Your guidance and assistance is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is a very similar function in the `List` theory in the standard library. That function takes a predicate as an argument, i.e. a function `f` from the element type to `bool`, and it returns `Some x` if a matching element `x` is found, or `None` if none is found.

```
Variable A : Type.
Fixpoint find (f:A->bool) (l:list A) : option A :=
  match l with
    | nil => None
    | x :: tl => if f x then Some x else find tl
  end.
```

You're looking for an element that's equal to a particular object `a`. That means your predicate is `eq_Interface a`, where `eq_Interface` is the equality you want over the `Interface`.

It's up to you to define an equality function on your type, because there can be many definitions of equality. Coq defines `=`, which is [Leibniz equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_law): two values are equal iff there is no way to distinguish between them. `=` is a proposition, not a boolean, because this property is not decidable in general. It's also not always the desirable equality on a type, sometimes you want a coarser equivalence relation, so that two objects can be considered equal if they were constructed in different ways but nonetheless have the same meaning.

If `Interface` is a simple datatype — intuitively, a data structure with no embedded proposition — there's a built-in tactic to build a structural equality function from the type definition. Look up `decide equality` in the reference manual.

```
Definition Interface_dec : forall x y : Interface, {x=y} + {x <> y}.
Proof. decide equality. Defined.
Definition Interface_eq x y := if Interface_dec x y then true else false.
```

`Interface_dec` not only tells you whether its arguments are equal, but also comes with a proof that the arguments are equal or that they're different.

Once you have that equality function, you can define your `find` function in terms of the standard library function:

```
Definition Interface_is_in x := if List.find (Interface_eq x) then true else false.
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm, I'll not spoil the fun by giving working code :). You are obviously missing something. Is your problem of how to code it in Coq or is it more general? How would you write it in pseudo-code? Or in some other language that you are familiar with?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its really just a problem of how to code in Coq. Ive managed to come up with the correct recursive definition. I have realised that I need to code my own separate equality function, as the beq_nat function found at: http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Arith.EqNat.html#beq_nat. However, this only compares elements of type nat. I have elements of type "Interface" custom data type which i have defined at the beginning. I know I cant have-because of the beq_nat:
Definition equal (i : Interface) (i' : Interface) :=
   if beq_nat (Interface1 i) (Interface2 i') then true else false.

Comment: If you show us the definition of the Interface I may try to help by telling you how to define equality over it.
Assuming you have such an equality how would you fix your above definition of `find`?